# Does nodejs make html pages faster?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have nodejs serve every file on my website, does it load faster than just plain HTML? Say, for instance, I had a site with loads of pictures. Does having expressjs serve them make the content load faster on page load?

Comment: Faster than what? Apache?

Comment: Test it and find out.  If you build a more efficient web server than Apache (that's even remotely as feature-rich), be proud of yourself.  Also, what does any of this have to do with "just plain HTML"?

Comment: NodeJS is just another way of serving things and expressjs is a library to help enable you serve things. You could choose to write a server in Java or C++ or for all I care, a shell script.  It has no advantages over other implementations unless you code it with those advantages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Nodejs has an http server module 'baked-in', but it's not necessarily faster than using any other HTTP server like Apache or Nginx.

In fact, you're likely to have Apache or Nginx fronting Node so that you can enable multiple domains on any given server.

If you're looking for blazing fast HTML service, you should look into cacheing your HTML pages in-mem using something like Redis.

Comment: Or using a CDN, which can boost performance for mostly static pages.

Comment: FWIW node can also host multiple domains just as well.

Answer (score -1):

No. It is more likely to make it slower since your application won't be optimised (compared to most HTTP servers) for serving static content.

Comment: How do you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @mscdex — Because webservers that are optimised for serving static content exist, NodeJS is a tool for running JavaScript, and while you can write an HTTP server in it, nobody is crowing about the performance benefits of doing so.

Comment: It seems like if you're making statements like this, you should back it up with real evidence.

Comment: http://zgadzaj.com/benchmarking-nodejs-basic-performance-tests-against-apache-php I think Node is generally considered faster when it comes to handling multiple requests at once.

Comment: @neilsimp1 — That isn't comparing the serving of static files